# rangevalidator for textbox for max & min date is not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime-format, date-range

I am using following code in page load but it give Error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `System.DateTime` to `string`

so i have change RangeValidators type to string; but its not working, I want that textbox should contain date between max & min value specified at runtime?

```
 yr1 =Convert.ToString(Session["FYear"]);

 yr=yr1.Split('-');
 startyr = yr[0].ToString();
 endyr = yr[1].ToString();
 dt1 = "01/04/" + startyr;
 dt2 = "31/03/" + endyr;

 RangeValidator1.MinimumValue =Convert.ToDateTime(dt1);
 RangeValidator1.MaximumValue = Convert.ToDateTime(dt2);
```

Comment: I am going to down vote this question because it shows the author did no research at all before asking it.

Comment: @Ramhound: I am not sure that voting down is the best way to support beginners ..

Comment: Also use the Type to set the DataType so that the range is properly calculated

Comment: @Akram - The author needs to learn how to research a problem before asking for help.

Comment: @Ramhound: then ask him to research the problem ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RangeValidator` 's `MinimumValue` and `MaximumValue` are of the type `System.String`. That's why you are getting the error.

Edit your code:

```
RangeValidator1.MinimumValue = dt1;
RangeValidator1.MaximumValue = dt2;
```

---

Read about [RangeValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator.aspx)